# добавить в список строку в её исходном виде

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list_ = []
str_ = "...\path\..."
list_.append(str_)
print(list_)

output: ['...\\path\\...']
```

Как можно добавить в список строку в её исходном виде?

Answer (score 1):

```
list_ = []
str_ = "D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\test.txt"
list_.append(str_)

str_ = "D:/_Qt/__Qt/test.txt"
list_.append(str_)

print(*list_, sep=("\n"))
D:\_Qt\__Qt\test.txt
D:/_Qt/__Qt/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотри нюанс

```
a = []
s = r'aa\123\rrr'
a.append(s)

print('Это начальная строка: ', s)
print('Это список: ', a)
print('Это значение со список a[0]: ', a[0])

if a[0] == s:
    print('строки равны!!!!')

#Вывод
# Это начальная строка:  aa\123\rrr
# Это список:  ['aa\\123\\rrr']
# Это значение со списка a[0]:  aa\123\rrr
# строки равны!!!!
```